# Opening a file with std::string

Tags: c++, stl, file-io

This should be a fairly trivial problem. I'm trying to open an ofstream using a std::string (or std::wstring) and having problems getting this to work without a messy conversion.

```
std::string path = ".../file.txt";

ofstream output;

output.open(path);
```

Ideally I don't want to have to convert this by hand or involve c-style char pointers if there's a nicer way of doing this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the path string, use two dots instead of three.

Also you may use 'c_str()' method on string to get the underlying C string.

```
output.open(path.c_str());
```

Answer (score 2):

this should work:

`output.open(path.c_str())`

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it's simply not possible. You have to use c_str, and yes, it sucks.

Incidentally, using char* also means fstream has no support for Unicode file names... a shame.

Comment: wfstream for std::wstring anyone?

Comment: No need for a special stream type, just overload open() to take a std::wstring.

Comment: basic_fstream's constructor accepts _only_ const char * (never wchar_t). See the standard: 27.8.1.6

Comment: @Assaf - I know what is in the standard, I was replying to KTC's comment about making another stream class, which doesn't make sense.